# Contar saltos de linea generados en un Multicell FPDF PHP

Tags: php, web, pdf, fpdf

Estoy trabajando con FPDF, tengo el siguiente código:

$pdf->MultiCell(30,10,'Esta es mi cadena larga','C')

El problema es que Multicell al detectar que una palabra no cabe en la celda agrega un salgo de linea y continua en la parte de abajo, lo que me interesa es obtener el número de lineas que agregó, el posible hacer eso?

Por ejemplo 'Esta es mi cadena larga'
quedaría así:

Esta es
mi cadena
larga

por lo tanto Multicell agregó tres saltos de linea, es posible recuperar esa información?

Comment: Lo que te interesa es contar la cantidad de saltos de linea que se producen en todo el pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Yo no tengo esa respuesta, pero lo solucione contando los caracteres para obtener las filas o saltos de linea.

```
//Contar letras de descripcion para ajustar alto

$Caracteres = strlen($Descripcion);

     //Dividimos los caracteres entre los que caben en una columna
     $Tot = $Caracteres/65;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

     //Redondeamos el resultado y lo multiplicamos por el alto de las filas
        $Filas = ceil($Tot);
        $Alto = ($Filas == 0)? 4 : $Filas * 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

hace poco trabaje con fpdf y añadi una pequeña modificacion al codigo para que devolviera el numero de renglones que usa el multicell.

```
function MultiCell($w, $h, $txt, $border=0, $align='J', $fill=false)
{
    // Output text with automatic or explicit line breaks
    if(!isset($this->CurrentFont))
        $this->Error('No font has been set');
    $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s = str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb = strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 && $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $b = 0;
    if($border)
    {
        if($border==1)
        {
            $border = 'LTRB';
            $b = 'LRT';
            $b2 = 'LR';
        }
        else
        {
            $b2 = '';
            if(strpos($border,'L')!==false)
                $b2 .= 'L';
            if(strpos($border,'R')!==false)
                $b2 .= 'R';
            $b = (strpos($border,'T')!==false) ? $b2.'T' : $b2;
        }
    }
    $sep = -1;
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $l = 0;
    $ns = 0;
    $nl = 1;
    $count = 1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        // Get next character
        $c = $s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            // Explicit line break
            if($this->ws>0)
            {
                $this->ws = 0;
                $this->_out('0 Tw');
            }
            $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j),$b,2,$align,$fill);
            $i++;
            $sep = -1;
            $j = $i;
            $l = 0;
            $ns = 0;
            $nl++;
            if($border && $nl==2)
                $b = $b2;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
        {
            $sep = $i;
            $ls = $l;
            $ns++;
        }
        $l += $cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            $count++;
            // Automatic line break
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
                if($this->ws>0)
                {
                    $this->ws = 0;
                    $this->_out('0 Tw');
                }
                $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j),$b,2,$align,$fill);
            }
            else
            {
                if($align=='J')
                {
                    $this->ws = ($ns>1) ? ($wmax-$ls)/1000*$this->FontSize/($ns-1) : 0;
                    $this->_out(sprintf('%.3F Tw',$this->ws*$this->k));
                }
                $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$sep-$j),$b,2,$align,$fill);
                $i = $sep+1;
            }
            $sep = -1;
            $j = $i;
            $l = 0;
            $ns = 0;
            $nl++;
            if($border && $nl==2)
                $b = $b2;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    // Last chunk
    if($this->ws>0)
    {
        $this->ws = 0;
        $this->_out('0 Tw');
    }
    if($border && strpos($border,'B')!==false)
        $b .= 'B';
    $this->Cell($w,$h,substr($s,$j,$i-$j),$b,2,$align,$fill);
    $this->x = $this->lMargin;
    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cuál fue la _pequeña modificación_.